# Javascript not to apply color

Tags: javascript, svg

Please HELP
How I Can to set javascript not to apply color white to "path class="st0" "?

All color is possible use only one In picture "S" - not possible fill white color, it is patch .st0. Fill another color is possible (only not white).

```
<svg id="swatches" width="60px" height="100px" style="" viewBox="-4 -4 60 100">    <rect style="fill:black"    x="0"  y="0" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect style="fill:#fe9000" x="25" y="0" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect style="fill:#ff0000" x="0"  y="25" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect style="fill:#ffff00"    x="25" y="25" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect style="fill:#0080ff" x="0"  y="50" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect style="fill:#1cb21c" x="25" y="50" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect style="fill:white" x="0"  y="75" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect style="fill:#f70b79"    x="25" y="75" width="20" height="20"/>
     <rect id="selection" style="stroke:#0000ff; stroke-opacity: 1;fill:none" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"/>
  </svg> 
 
 
      
 
  <svg id="omalovanka" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000px" height="350px" viewBox="1 28 437 196.7" style="fill:#fff;stroke: #000;">
<style type="text/css">
 
    .st0{fill:grey;stroke:#08090A;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#dedede;stroke:#08090A;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;} 
</style>
 
 
 
<path class="st1" d="M266.5,79.3c0,0.2,8.9,16.1,8.9,16.1s0.9,2.1-0.9,4.8c-1.8,2.7-9.5,3.2-10.8,3.4c-1.3,0.1-8.3,0.2-19.2,0.5
    s-12.7,1.5-16.9,4.1s-3.2,5.5-3.2,5.5l4.9,8.4c5.4,10,35.2,8.9,35.2,8.9c61.5,2.2,192.2-5.4,192.2-5.4l0.3,0.5V116
    c0,0-8.7-8.3-13.5-11.7c-4.6-3.2-60-32.1-189.7-34.4C262.9,71.9,266.5,79.1,266.5,79.3z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M207.9,131.8c0,0-6.2-10.3-12.7-19.2c-6.5-8.9-3.8-10.3-3.8-10.3c1.6-8.1,21.1-8.4,21.1-8.4s17.3,0.5,27.3-0.5
    s6-7.3,6-7.3c-3-8.9-13.5-8.7-13.5-8.7C102.3,79,44.1,101.2,44.1,101.2c-16.5,5.3-27.5,12.4-33.2,16.9V129
    c32.8,10.3,165.5,12.7,212.5,13.2C213.3,138.8,207.9,131.8,207.9,131.8z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M234,142.3c3.9,0,6.1,0,6.1,0v-0.1c42.6-0.4,183-2.6,216.9-13.3v-2.9l-0.3-0.5c0,0-130.8,7.6-192.2,5.4
    c0,0-29.8,1.1-35.2-8.9l-4.9-8.4c0,0-1.1-2.9,3.2-5.5s6-3.7,16.9-4.1s17.9-0.4,19.2-0.5c1.3-0.1,9-0.7,10.8-3.4
    c1.8-2.7,0.9-4.8,0.9-4.8s-8.9-15.9-8.9-16.1c0-0.2-3.5-7.4-12.6-9.4c-6.4-0.1-13-0.2-19.8-0.1C90,69.2,29.3,100.9,24.5,104.3
    c-4.9,3.4-13.5,11.7-13.5,11.7v2.1c5.7-4.4,16.7-11.6,33.2-16.9c0,0,58.2-22.2,188.1-23.8c0,0,10.6-0.3,13.5,8.7c0,0,4.1,6.2-6,7.3
    s-27.3,0.5-27.3,0.5s-19.5,0.3-21.1,8.4c0,0-2.7,1.4,3.8,10.3c6.5,8.9,12.7,19.2,12.7,19.2s5.4,7,15.5,10.4c0.8,0,1.5,0,2.3,0v0.7
    c-3.9,0-7.8,0.1-11.6,0.1c-9.1,2.1-12.6,9.2-12.6,9.4c0,0.2-8.9,16.1-8.9,16.1s-0.9,2.1,0.9,4.8c1.8,2.7,9.5,3.2,10.8,3.4
    c1.3,0.1,8.3,0.2,19.2,0.5s12.7,1.5,16.9,4.1c4.3,2.6,3.2,5.5,3.2,5.5l-4.9,8.4c-5.4,10-35.2,8.9-35.2,8.9
    c-61.5,2.2-192.2-5.4-192.2-5.4l-0.3,0.5v2.9c33.9,10.7,174.4,12.8,216.9,13.3v0.1c0,0,2.2,0,6.1,0c3.9,0,6.1,0,6.1,0v-0.1
    c1.4,0,2.8,0,4.4,0c10.1-3.4,15.5-10.4,15.5-10.4s6.2-10.3,12.7-19.2c6.5-8.9,3.8-10.3,3.8-10.3c-1.6-8.1-21.1-8.4-21.1-8.4
    s-17.3,0.5-27.3-0.5c-10-1.1-6-7.3-6-7.3c3-8.9,13.5-8.7,13.5-8.7c129.9,1.6,188.1,23.8,188.1,23.8c16.5,5.3,27.5,12.4,33.2,16.9
    v-2.1c0,0-8.7-8.3-13.5-11.7c-4.8-3.4-65.6-35-209.5-34.5c-2.8,0-5.5,0-8.2,0l0-0.7c0.7,0,1.4,0,2.1,0v0.1
    C227.9,142.3,230,142.3,234,142.3z"/>
</svg>
 
   
<script>
 
 var _currentFill = "fill:#000";
  var _pouziteBarvy = new Array();
  var _vypln = new Boolean(true);
  $("#octocat").click(function (event) {
      for (i = 0; i < _pouziteBarvy.length; i++){
          if(_pouziteBarvy[i] == _currentFill){
           _vypln = false;
           break;
         }
      }
      if(_vypln && event.target.nodeName == "path"){
         var i = _pouziteBarvy.indexOf($(event.target).attr('style'));
         if(i != -1) {
        _pouziteBarvy.splice(i, 1);
    }                 
         $(event.target).attr('style', _currentFill);
         _pouziteBarvy.push(_currentFill);
      }
      _vypln = true;             
  })
  var $swatches = $("#swatches");
  $swatches.click(function (event) { 
      $swatch = $(event.target);
      loc = [parseInt($swatch.attr('x'), 10), parseInt($swatch.attr('y'), 10)]
      $("#selection", $swatches).attr('x', loc[0]);
      $("#selection", $swatches).attr('y', loc[1]);
      if( event.target.nodeName != "svg"){
          _currentFill = $swatch.attr('style');
      }
  })
```

............................................................................................................

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code example as a starting point, for example in https://stackblitz.com/. It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

In JS you can try:

```
document.querySelector(".st1").setAttribute("style", "fill: transparent;");
```

However, you are already filling `st1` path in your CSS here.

```
.st1{fill:#dedede;stroke:#08090A;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
```

Unless required, You could simply use`fill:transparent` here itself, without going to javascript file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
All color is possible use only one
In picture "S" - not possible fill white color, it is patch .st0 (not .st1 - my mistake). Fill another color is possible (only not white).

Comment: U are welcome Monika. Hmmm. Got it. If my answer has helped you do accept it and vote for it. It motivates me to help other's :) Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not, my problem was not solved :-(((
patch st0 is possible fill color red, blue, green... and so on, but not white. 
____________________________________
Code must be:

if use white color => not fill patch .st0 ________________________
if use any another color (9 color from 10)=> fill patch .st0
________________________________________________
i don't know how to write to code :-(

Comment: Ooo, I see ... What you  are trying to say is : When you are using white color  we have to use fill property.  But where. Do you mean when in your HTML file you have color white set for st0, In Javascript we must change it... Is this what you mean :)

Comment: I made a preview of what colors can be used where.
Each color can be used only once.
https://i.ibb.co/RPfcm4y/color.jpg

Comment: OK... nice art by the way

Comment: Hello Monila . Hope you are doing good.  Let me try to help you out..Hopefully :)

Comment: ok, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Oh, dear !!!  I got occupied with other work ...Forgot to help you. My Apology !!! Let  me see what we can do with this :)

Comment: its all right ;-)

Comment: I tried to fix it but not able to :) Have not worked with SVG in the past ... Also I don't use JQuery anymore... Sorry couldn't  do this :)

Comment: ok, thank you for your effort ;-)